# Run external command in awk

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

Is it possible to perform an action using if and else statement with awk

```
ps -ef | grep crond | awk '{ if ($1 =="root") print $1 $2}'
```

The command above greps for process crond and if it is owned by root it will print it.
However instead of the print command I like to cal a function or execute a command line 
(example `kill -9 $1`). Basically killing the cron process if any owned by root

Is it is possible to call a command ( example `kill -9 $1` )  or call a function using `awk`?
can you provide an example please on how to call a function or a command?

Comment: system(your command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `system` function in awk:

```
ps -ef | awk '/crond/ && $1 == "root"{system("kill " $2)}'
```

Also no need to use `grep` since `awk` can handle this.

Comment: hank you . I was using this example , to find out how to find a function call using awk. I intend to use if statement in awk and then cal la command or a script. I was wondering if u could provide an example that has if statement in it calling a function or a command line utility –  ?  Thx

Comment: I have shown an example of calling an external shell command from awk using awk variable `$2` under condition `/crond/ && $1 == "root"`. Which part is not clear to you?

Comment: It is very clear and thank you. So instead of the current condition Can I put in an "if statement"? and how would I call a function within a script?  THX

Comment: Yes definitely `/crond/ && $1 == "root"` can also be written as: `awk '{if ($0 ~ /crond/ && $1 == "root" {system("kill " $2)}}'`

Comment: Great! , Can u please clarify one more point? does $0 ~ mean? Mean  if there are  any crond process not = zero?  Secondly, can I plug in a script-function instead of command line . So would I use {system("my-function-name $2}" Cheeers

Comment: `$0 ~ /crond/` is matching string `"crond"` anywhere in whole line since `$0` represents whole line. It is same as `grep "crond"` Yes you can call your script using `system`

Comment: thx. However I was talking about a function .. Not a script. But Th x for ur help

Answer (score 1):

You can directly `kill` what comes from the output:

```
kill $(ps -ef | awk '/crond/ && $1=="root" {print $2}')
```

This performs a `ps -ef` and prints the 2nd column for those lines containing `crond` together with `root` as the first column.

Comment: thank you . I was using this example , to find out how to find a function call using awk. I intend to use if statement in awk and then cal la command or a script. I was wondering if u could provide an example that has if statement in it calling a function or a command line utility

Comment: anubhava's answer address the problem very well. Refer to his answer!

Comment: ok thx for ur help I rephrased my question waiting for him to respond